# Having trouble in testing whether the object I pass in to a function is a list or vector

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I can't make sense of my results

Here is my code in **DrRacket**:

---

```
(define (checkType . x)
  (cond
    [(vector? x) (display "x is a vector")]
    [(list? x) (display "x is a list")]      
    [#t (newline)]
  ))
```

---

#### Output (REPL):

```
> (checkType (make-vector 3 #(1 2 3)))
x is a list

> (checkType (make-vector 3 #(1 2 3)))
x is a list

> (vector? (make-vector 3 #(1 2 3)))
#t

> (list? (make-vector 3 #(1 2 3)))
#f
```

---

This is where my issue is.

Why isn't it displaying `"x is a vector"` when I pass in a vector? In fact, when I pass in a vector, it even passes the condition that checks if it's a list. Shouldn't this never happen and skip to the very last expression? As shown in the output, `make-vector` creates a vector and not a list.

Am I misinterpreting the semantics of something here?

Comment: Why is there a `.` dot before the `x` parameter? Take it out. The `.` means that the `x` will be treated as the "varargs" rest paramater, a list containing all the rest of the arguments. Take the `.` out, and the `x` will be a normal parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is there a `.` dot before the `x` parameter? Take it out. The `.` means that the `x` will be treated as the "varargs" rest parameter, a list containing all the rest of the arguments. Take the `.` out, and the `x` will be a normal parameter.

```
(define (checkType x)
  (cond
    [(vector? x) (displayln "x is a vector")]
    [(list? x) (displayln "x is a list")]      
    [else (newline)]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I added the `.` there because I wanted to practice the idea of writing a function that takes an arbitrary amount of arguments, but I forgot to realize that doing so causes it to be interpreted as a list of arguments. At least, that's how I understand the problem.

I now obtain the correct results in the output.